# Move instance zone secured-sql-server-2016-stand-win-ser-2016-1-vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Experiencing difficulty learning if it is possible to switch an instance location: secured-sql-server-2016-stand-win-ser-2016-1-vm it is currently in us-central1-f I need it to be in an Australian Zone. Technical consultant might be helpful if this is even possible, otherwise I'll need to change cloud servers.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, instances stay in a zone. "Moving" them means backing up, deleting, and recreating somewhere else.

There are procedures and APIs for doing so. See [moving instances across zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones).